# Nodejs and Expressjs sending ajax post request

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express, redis

I'm having a problem in sending post data in `http://localhost:1111/user/create`.  I'm using Expressjs framework and Redis as my database. The main problem is it does not get the value of the textbox in my client and after sending the post data all the value of field in redis is undefined. I don't know what's wrong here but here's my code:

`app.post` in **server.js**

```
app.post('/user/create', function(req, res) {

    var user = req.body.user;
    var pass = req.body.pass;
    var name = req.body.name;
    var email = req.body.email;

    return client.hmset('username:' + user, 'password', pass, 'name', name, 'email', email,
            function(err, data) {
                if (!err) {
                    return res.send(data);
                    return console.log(data);
                } else {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
            });
});
```

Here's the jquery on how to send post data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#createbutton").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = {};
                data.name = $('#nameinput').val();
                data.email = $('#emailinput').val();
                data.username = $('#usernameinput').val();
                data.password = $('#passwordinput').val();
                JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(data);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:1111/user/create',
                    data: {data},
                    dataType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I've already check the client and server but I can't figure out what the error is. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: There's no need for client side though if you have given names of input fields in your form the same way you given to variables and have bodyparser, then no need to send something from client-side with ajax. Bodyparser initializes everything in server-side and you can use it directly on the client-side with `req.body`

Answer (score 2):

Your data variable is wrong, Change you js code to below and try once:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $("#createbutton").submit(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = {};
                data.name = $('#nameinput').val();
                data.email = $('#emailinput').val();
                data.user = $('#usernameinput').val();
                data.pass = $('#passwordinput').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://localhost:1111/user/create',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log('success');
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

You will need to use bodyParser middleware to access post variables. This middleware takes raw post data and assigns values to req.body object. check http://expressjs.com/api.html#bodyParser

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: It seems like you are sending wrong parameters in data and accessing it in server with wrong names.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45361/discussion-between-yalamber-and-user2717352)

Comment: It seems like your jquery code is not correct. can you send your html codes?

Answer (score -4):

I don't know about `expressjs` but you can try to change your `dataType` from this:

```
dataType: 'application/json'
```

to:

```
dataType: 'json'
```